# Short story about the last two people on Earth; Earth has been paved all over but a small plant grows in concrete

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

During the 1980s when I was a child, I read a science fiction short story that I believe was part of a larger anthology. If memory serves me, the anthology was a trade paperback with a blue cover.

The story revolved around a young woman who had befriended an older man. The Earth was being evacuated because it was no longer habitable, having been completely paved over. The young woman went to retrieve the old man to get on the last ship off of Earth. When she arrived at his home, she found him observing a green stalk of a plant that had grown in an area of the concrete that he had broken up. He decided he did not want to leave Earth.

Comment: Obligatory librarian meme: http://weknowmemes.com/2014/02/i-dont-remember-the-title-but-its-blue/

Comment: So, there may be more information you can dredge up. Anything from [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) may help, but two things I'd like to know are: How short? Less than a page? More than 10? Novella- length? Also, do you remember if the author was a relatively famous one or not?

Comment: Strongly reminiscent of the previews of the recently released movie *Io*, but that appears to be an original story.